# Non-destructive parsing and modifying of HTML elements in C++

Tags: c++, html-parsing

I have a need to do some simple modifications to HTML in C++, preferably without completely rewriting the HTML, such as what happens when I use libxml2 or MSHTML.

In particular I need to be able to read, and then (potentially) modify, the "src" attribute of all "img" elements. I need it to be robust enough to be able to do this with any valid HTML, but preferably without changing any of the other HTML in the process.

Are there any libraries out there that would be able to handle this? Or is this something I can do with regular expressions? I'm not too savvy with regular expressions, and I've read a lot of questions here that say you shouldn't use them to parse HTML, but I'm not clear if that applies to something like this or if that principle applies primarily to parsing in the context of building a tree from the HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your constraint. Using the DOM does not completely rewrite the HTML.

Comment: @EBGreen, libxml adds an <xml> tag, a <DOCTYPE> tag, and reformats all of the HTML. MSHTML changes all of the tags to uppercase, and reformats it all. And since valid HTML can still be displayed in a browser, breaking it into a DOM often leaves stuff out that is in the original HTML. I'd like to leave the original HTML as intact as I can, because people may still be doing designs at the other end of my product, and if they see HTML that looks vastly different than what they're trying to produce, that can be a problem.

Comment: Sorry that should have said "since INVALID HTML can still be displayed..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions aren't recommended for HTML because they don't handle nested tags well. They should be fine for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks, that's about what I gathered from the other questions/answers, but I wasn't positive. I suppose this could be a good excuse for me to finally learn regular expressions.

Comment: I'd recommend it. They're extremely useful, and the learning curve really isn't that steep.

Comment: I used to dabble with regex in Perl about 8 or 9 years ago, but I've pretty much forgotten it all. But I just grabbed Boost Regex, and was able to figure out how to do what I needed to do in about an hour, with about 10 lines of code. And I ordered a couple of books on the subject, so I can actually understand everything I did :P

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at [HTMLTidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/)

I have used it for similar things in the past.